# Execute .bat file from VBA vs Execute .bat file with manually clicking

Tags: batch-file, excel, vba

I'm new to this and hopefully I am doing it correctly.

I have a bat file that will search for a register key under hklm\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat.  The Bat file returns the answer when I manually click on it, but fails to search for the key when it is called by Shell with Excel VBA.  Here's the bat file:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set xx=2
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%D in (
'reg query \\servername"\hklm\software\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat" /s /v Version'
) do (
if !xx!==1 set "var3=%%D,"
set /a "xx = xx - 1"
)
if "%var3%"=="" (set "var3= ,")
echo %var3%
pause
```

and here's how it is called by vba:
    Call Shell("C:\Users\mynetworkID\desktop\c.bat")

It runs the bat file correctly but it fails to search for the register key.  Any ideas why?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Try taking the @echo off line out: see what it's actually doing

Comment: It displays the code blocks but the error remains when I run the bat with VBA.  FYI this is the error message:
Error: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

Comment: Are you running as administrator when you run it manually? Or as the same user running Excel?

Comment: Same user as admininistrator.  There's only one user profile on my computer as admin and that's what I am currently using.  T

Comment: I've set that up on my machine (changed the servername to my local machine name). When I run it directly and from VBA it gave me the error as the key doesn't exist. I created the key and ran again. Both did the same thing. Are you sure you're runing the same copy of the bat file?

Comment: Thanks for testing it on your machine.  Do you mean the code gives your the error message even the registry key is present?  Also I Double checked and I am positive I am running the same copy.

Comment: No - once I created the key it ran without an error message. I don't think it did anything though.

Comment: It actually gives me a clue - everything works fine when it's local.  Even when I have administrative right on the remote server, does it make a different if it is ran manually vs code initiate?

Comment: Sorry I should make myself clear.  I am still running the code / clicking the .bat at my local machine.  And I have admin right on the remote server that I am extracting the information

Comment: It might. UAT could be coming into play; its definitely something to do with the ACL on the Registry key I think.

Comment: Many thanks.  I will do some research on ACL on Registry Key.  Thanks for your helps!

Comment: No problem - good luck! PS If you're in an AD Domain, there will be Group Policies to check into as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell() cannot bypass the regsvr32.exe without permission, and ShellExecute API can be used instead:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238245

Wish I have the code for it but now the project is not in my hand anymore